# How can I use mvnrnd function in simulation?

Tags: matlab, simulation

when using mvnrnd function we use mean and covariance matrix which is positive semi definite my question is:

When using this function in simulation the covariance matrix sometimes is not positive semi definite how can I deal with it? Using chol function? If so how?

Comment: Covariance matrices are always positive semi-definite. How are you constructing them? Is it perhaps a numerical precision problem?

Answer (score 0):

Very similar discussion [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/118988)

The short answer is that your input (which is output from your simulation) is not valid. This could be for a few reasons.

Without knowing your situation, I would point you to [this resource](http://www2.gsu.edu/~mkteer/npdmatri.html) to figure out why you are getting covariances that are not positive semi-definite, and the last section of that site gives a method of "side-stepping" the problem.